# Proving that the boundary of domain does not contain line segments

Tags: differential-topology

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain. If $\partial D$ is a real-analytic sub-manifold, it is not very difficult to show that $\partial D$ does not contain any line segments. Now, assume that $\partial D$ is a finite disjoint union of (connected) real-analytic sub-manifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that there is precisely one sub-manifold of dimension $n-1$, say $B$. Is it true that $B$ does not contain any line segments?

Comment: Are you still assuming each of the components of the disjoint union are real analytic? Are you assuming anything else about $D$? As stated, the question looks trivially false to me. 

Comment: Elaborating on "trivially false", consider the domain $(x-(1-z^2))^2+y^2\le (1-z^2)^2$, $-1\le z\le 1$. 

Comment: @willie Wong Yes I am assuming that each component is real-analytic. 